# Logging off ios app and returning to RootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uinavigationcontroller, rootview

I created a RootViewController in my app delegate like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    StartViewController *viewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init];
    StartNavigationController *navigationController=[[StartNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

When I hit the logout button, I want to send the user back to the rootview controller:

```
- (IBAction) logoutButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [Users logOut];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This works fine when I run it on my iPhone 4s (testing iphone 6 when it arrives), but if I leave the user logged in for more than a day and click the logout button, the screen slides to black.

Why is my root view controller not calling my startviewcontroller after like 24 hours or so?

Comment: anyone got any advice?

Comment: I suspect the viewcontroller is deallocated? Try put for(UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers){ NSLog(@"Class %@",NSStringFromClass([controller class])); } in logout function before poping out. See if it exists

Comment: Deallocation would be my guess too.  How can I just create the StartViewController *viewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init]; and add it to the self.navigationcontroller? Do I check if it's nil?

Comment: See my answer, I think this way we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to put an answer, I guess it should work for you. First you check for `StartViewController` whether it exist in navigationController stack or, not. As per your stack `StartViewController` should be your first controller added in `navigationController`.

```
StartViewController *loginController=[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];


if(loginController){
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:loginController animated:YES];
}else{
    NSMutableArray *controllers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   loginController=[[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartViewController" bundle:nil];
    [controllers addObject:loginController];
    [controllers addObjectsFromArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    self.navigationController.viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:controllers];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I think it should work.

Cheers.

Comment: Seems logical so we shall see when I wake up manana if my app works fine or not.  Does the simulator do anything funky, like deallocate stuff differently? I'm running this app on my iphone 4s device.